# Using NLP in Python how to find what a person did in a report?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have a large text file which contains some reports of who did what and when. Now I want to know how to extract for example "John" did in this reports? there may be lots of thing he did.

I used some code this is one of them but I code not get the answer.

```
import re
import spacy

# Load the language model
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# Define the person you want to search for
person = "John"

# Define a regular expression pattern to match the person's name
pattern = re.compile(fr"\b{person}\b", re.IGNORECASE)



# Process the text with the language model
doc = nlp(text)

# Extract the relevant information
actions = []
for sent in doc.sents:
    for token in sent:
        if pattern.match(token.text):
            for child in token.children:
                if child.dep_ == "ROOT":
                    actions.append(child.text)
                    

# Print the results
if actions:
    print(f"{person} did the following actions: {' '.join(actions)}")
else:
    print(f"No actions found for {person}.")
```

Answer (score 0):

From my limited understanding of spacy, iterating over the `token.ancestors` instead of the `token.children` should solve your issue.

```py
# [your code]
for sent in doc.sents:
    for token in sent:
        if pattern.match(token.text):
            for child in token.ancestors:  # replace children by ancestors
# [your code]
```